# Fetching max number from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have applied `select MAX(index_no) from Checkin_master` .

I am getting int value in my cursor. but i dont know method to store that value in integer.my code is as following.

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select MAX(index_no) from CheckIN_master",null);
         if(c!=null){
             while(c.moveToNext())
             {
                 in_no=c.
             }
         }
```

Please help me.

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
 Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select MAX(index_no) as MAX_NO from CheckIN_master",null);
     if(c!=null){
         while(c.moveToNext())
         {
             in_no=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("MAX_NO"));
         }
     }
```